# How to change tab background color programmatically?

Tags: android, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am trying to change the background color of selected (active tab). My case is by default all tabs are white when user select the tab it gets the color I want.
I am using a library name  **PagerSlidingTabStrip** ... what I tried so far is:

On tab change I call this code. It works very fine and change the text color. Now all I want to change the same tab background color.

```
private void setSelectedTabColor(int position) {
    for(int i=0; i<tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++)  
    {  
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) tabStrip.getChildAt(0);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.getChildAt(i);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
    }  

    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) tabStrip.getChildAt(0);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.getChildAt(position);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}
```

By trying the below code in loop, I get null pointer exception.

```
tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dash_bar));
```

Comment: Post `tabStrip` loop(I'm not a downvoter)

Comment: Its in setSelectedTabColor function look above.

Comment: That loop for `userBabies` not for `tabStrip`

Comment: userBabies  are tabsCOunt

Comment: Try It: `textView.getParent().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dash_bar));`

Comment: it solved the problem?

Comment: I tried this: textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
     R.color.dash_bar));

Comment: Hey Can I post an answer could you accept it with upvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines to change the background of particular child.

```
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) tabStrip.getChildAt(0);      
TextView textView = (TextView) view.getChildAt(position);
textView.getParent().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
              R.color.dash_bar));
```